# How can I modify this script to change each value, rather than create a new column for new values?

Tags: powerquery

I have a massive dataset of over 20,000 records. There are certain values in certain columns that need to be replaced. I could write "find-replace" functions for each, but this would require over 200 replacement clauses.

I found two scripts that sort of accomplish what I'm looking for -- I think if I can combine aspects of those scripts, I can create what I need.

What I would like to do is reference another table that contains my find-replace values, and replace values accordingly in my excel table. I found a code that does this -- the issue is a new column is created for all the value replacements. I don't want to do that either because I have 60 columns of data that need to be modified, so I would need to run this function 60 times.

So essentially, I need to modify this script to modify the values as they are found. This is roughly what my tables look like:

The raw data:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| apple | banana |
| orange | grapefruit |

The find-replace table:

| Find | Replace |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 1 |
| garepfruit | 2 |

Expected output after running find-replace script:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana |
| orange | 2 |

I found a script which uses `list-generate` to do this... except with this script, I can only feed one column into the function, and then additional columns are created with the replacement values:

```
let
    //Get table of word replacements
    Replacements = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Replacements"]}[Content],
    //Get table containing text to change
    TextToChange = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Text"]}[Content],
    //Get list of words to replace
    WordsToReplace = Table.Column(Replacements, "Word ToReplace"),
    //Get list of words to replace them with
    WordsToReplaceWith = Table.Column(Replacements, "Replace With"),
    //A non-recursive function to do the replacements
    ReplacementFunction = (InputText)=> 
     let
       //Use List.Generate() to do the replacements
       DoReplacement = List.Generate(
                          ()=> [Counter=0, MyText=InputText], #Generate a list of records containing counter and mytext, where counter is a value and mytext is a variable fed into the function
                          each[Counter]<=List.Count(WordsToReplaceWith), #counter should be less than or equal to the number of values in wordstoreplacewith
                          each[Counter=[Counter]+1, #Counter should increase by 1 every time 
                                MyText=Text.Replace(
                                         [MyText], 
                                         WordsToReplace{[Counter]}, 
                                         WordsToReplaceWith{[Counter]})], 
                          each[MyText]),
       //Return the last item in the list that
       //List.Generate() returns
       GetLastValue = List.Last(DoReplacement)
     in
      GetLastValue,
    //Add a calculated column to call the function on every row in the table
    //containing the text to change
    Output= Table.AddColumn(TextToChange, "Changed Text", eachReplacementFunction([Text]))
in
    Output
```

I found a different script which accomplishes what I'm looking to do -- the issue is, it is too memory consuming on my computer. The authors of the scripts noted that `list generate` is a better option that is less recursive and so might be more well suited to large datasets. Here is the script that doesn't function with large datasets:

```
let BulkReplace = (DataTable as table, FindReplaceTable as table, DataTableColumn as list) =>
    let
        //Convert the FindReplaceTable to a list using the Table.ToRows function
        //so we can reference the list with an index number
        FindReplaceList = Table.ToRows(FindReplaceTable),
        //Count number of rows in the FindReplaceTable to determine
        //how many iterations are needed
        Counter = Table.RowCount(FindReplaceTable),
        //Define a function to iterate over our list 
        //with the Table.ReplaceValue function
        BulkReplaceValues = (DataTableTemp, n) => 
        let 
            //Replace values using nth item in FindReplaceList
            ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(
                DataTableTemp,
                //replace null with empty string in nth item
                if FindReplaceList{n}{0} = null then "" else FindReplaceList{n}{0},
                if FindReplaceList{n}{1} = null then "" else FindReplaceList{n}{1},
                Replacer.ReplaceText,
                DataTableColumn
                )
        in
            //if we are not at the end of the FindReplaceList
            //then iterate through Table.ReplaceValue again
            if n = Counter - 1 
                then ReplaceTable
                else @BulkReplaceValues(ReplaceTable, n + 1),
        //Evaluate the sub-function at the first row
        Output = BulkReplaceValues(DataTable, 0)   
    in
        Output
```

I think I could modify the first script to do what the bulk replace function is trying to do. However my modifications were not working, I think because I have a poor understanding of what certain parts of the functions are doing. Specifically, here are a few questions I have:

--> what does the line   `ReplacementFunction = (InputText)=>`mean?

--> what is the role of the counter exactly? I understand that the counter is first generated based on the length of the column with the replacement values, but I don't understand why the counter is being called in  `WordsToReplace{[Counter]}` and `WordsToReplaceWith{[Counter]})]`

---> in the bulk replace function, I don't understand what the following means:

```
//Evaluate the sub-function at the first row
        Output = BulkReplaceValues(DataTable, 0)
```

--> I also don't understand what this means:

```
 //Return the last item in the list that
       //List.Generate() returns
       GetLastValue = List.Last(DoReplacement)
```

I think if I understand these scripts better I can figure out how to combine the list generate function and the bulk replace function to get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you have a bunch of columns and you want to operate on a single column, add an index, right click the index, unpivot other columns. When done, repivot it back as needed

Here, you don't specify if you plan to replace text within larger text (such as **dog** within **there is a dog** or if the text to be replaced will be stand alone.  You also dont specify if there are multiple items in each cell to replace at once.  I will assume you check replace the entire text in each cell, once, as a group

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Value"}, Table1, {"Find"}, "Bucket", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Bucket", {"Replace"}, {"Replace"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table1", "Combine", each [Replace] ?? [Value]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value", "Replace"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Combine"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Comment: so the only thing is I am operating on 60+ columns. so I was trying to create a function where I could feed in a list of my columns to iterate through and make the find-replace changes to.

Comment: This will do a replace on all columns regardless of the number of columns.  If you want to skip certain columns, add those to the unpivot step along with Index.    Also, I answered how to apply a function across multiple columns right at the top of my answer if you have a better function you want to use

Comment: what is the purpose of the index column?

Comment: To allow repivot after unpivot

Comment: My question specifically asks for help modifying the scripts I currently have. While your solution does work (and I am very appreciative of it), I am hoping someone might respond with an answer that uses the scripts I provided. I am trying to broaden my understanding of Power Query M and am trying to get used to using custom functions, which is why I specifically asked for help modifying the existing functions I have. I hope you understand that I am very appreciative of the time you put into your answer.

Comment: actually what I will do is accept your solution and I will make a separate post addressing my specific questions about the scripts I provided. I don't want you to feel that your answer was not appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, but really all you need to do is add index, unpivot, apply you scripts against the single remaining column, repivot

Comment: yeah as I said your solution did work, I just was hoping to find a solution that uses the scripts I provided rather than using table pivoting and unpivoting.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way to say it

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your solution (and I did use it). I would just like to practice using custom functions.